# Clarification on the convergence of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{xe^x}dx$ - Spivak Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification

Question 46c) from Chapter 19 of Spivak's *Calculus* asks the reader to compute the following integral: $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}-e^{-\beta x}}{x}dx$.

The solution manual reads:

> Since $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$ converges and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}e^{-x}=1$, we have $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}-e^{-\beta x}}{x}dx=\log\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)$

, which is making use of a previously derived "Frullani Integral" variant theorem ( I think).

---

Firstly, **I wanted to confirm** that the statement "*Since $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$ converges...*" is false and should instead say:

> Since $\displaystyle \int_a^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$ converges (for any $a \gt 0$)...

Next, I want to prove that this statement is indeed true.

To do this, we will first prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_1^N \frac{1}{xe^x}dx$ converges. Second,  we will prove that for any $a \in (0,1]: \displaystyle \int_a^1\frac{1}{xe^x}dx$ exists and is finite.

**First:**

Suppose $x \geq 1$. Then $0<e^x \lt xe^x$. This implies that $0\lt\frac{1}{xe^x} \lt \frac{1}{e^x}$. Next, note that $\displaystyle \int_{1}^N\frac{1}{e^x}dx=-e^{-x} |^N_1=\frac{-1}{e^N}+\frac{1}{e} \to \frac{1}{e}$ as $N \to \infty$. As such, we must have that $\displaystyle\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_1^N\frac{1}{xe^x}dx \lt  \frac{1}{e}$...and this integral is strictly increasing, meaning it converges to some $L_{[1,\infty)} \lt \frac{1}{e}$.

**Second:**

Suppose $x \in (0,1]$. Because $e^x \geq 1$, then $0\lt x \lt xe^x$, which implies that $0 \lt \frac{1}{xe^x} \lt \frac{1}{x}$. As such, we must have that $\displaystyle \int_a^1  \frac{1}{xe^x} dx \lt \int_a^1 \frac{1}{x}dx=-\int_1^a\frac{1}{x}dx=-\log(a).$ Of course, then, we must have that: $ \displaystyle 0 \lt \int_a^1  \frac{1}{xe^x} \lt -\log(a)$.

We conclude that for any $a \in (0,1]$:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_a^N \frac{1}{xe^x}dx \lt L_{[1,\infty)} -\log(a)$$

and because this integral is strictly increasing, it must converge.

Also, for any $a \in [1, \infty)$, we note that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_a^N \frac{1}{xe^x}dx$ must converge at some value $\leq L_{[1,\infty)}$

Comment: This works. You could just note that $\frac{1}{xe^x}$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ for $a > 0$, so it suffices to show that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{xe^x}dx < \infty$.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed thank you for the quicker approach. Do you agree that the original phrasing (as provided by the solution manual) is incorrect?

Comment: Yea, the phrasing as given in the manual is incorrect. Spivak only needs that $\int_\delta^\infty \frac{1}{xe^x}dx < \infty$ for any $\delta > 0$, and then uses the limit definition of the improper integral with probably some Taylor expansion around $x= 0$ to conclude the result.